# Cordova and Django login, session expire

Tags: python, django, cordova, django-rest-framework

I have a backend in django, and endpoint (rest framework) to login.

simple ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : url+login/",
        data : {username:username, password:password}
    })
```

and simple view

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def login(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            auth.login(request, user)
            #When I type here: print request.session.items()
            #I get _auth_user... things.
        else:
            pass
   return Response({})
```

But when I change page in my native app, and there call another ajax e.g. url "test/", and this url call this view:

```
def test(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        print "Logged in
    else:
        #redirect to home...
    return response
```

Then request.user.is_authenticated return False, looks like session expire is to small, so I try this:

```
 ...
 auth.login(request, user)
 #When I type here: print request.session.items()
 #I get _auth_user... things.
 request.session.set_expire(0)
 ...
```

But this doesn't work.

** EDIT **
Im using Django Rest Framework. And 'turn on':

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
     'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}
```

Comment: You are not telling us what you are using for your rest framework. Can you confirm is django-rest-framework?

Comment: Yes, Django-rest-framework

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider using

```
'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'
```

which will be much easier to handle on a mobile app, as you can just store the token after login, and use that token for any other API call. It also allows you to safely use csrf_exempt

AFAIK, $.ajax won't send any cookies if you are crossing domains, which you are doing by definition from a mobile app. So, I think your issue has to do with CORS and how you initialize the ajax call.

Try using:

```
xhrFields: { withCredentials:true }
```

on your .ajax call.

You also need to set up CORS (use django-cors-headers)

See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/ for other things that you may need to worry about. In particular

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax

But as I said, consider using tokens instead of sessions.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you know nice articles which describe this token mechanism in django-rest + cordova?

Comment: I use Ionic/Angular but the concept is relatively simple. The code I posted on your other question about login shows how to return the token. So, all you need on the mobile side is to store that token on local storage (and delete when user logs out). And then use {'Authorization': 'token <token>'} on your header

Comment: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

Answer (score 0):

I've had troubles with Django and post variables before. 
Try changing your $.ajax call to:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "yourURL/",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    data : 'username='+encodeURIComponent(username)+'&password='+encodeURIComponent(password),
});
```